# Whats the best way to Parse a Lexicon and show a large amount of matches using wild cards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, text-parsing, fuzzy-search

My problem is, I have a lexicon of about 200,000 words or so.  The file is 1.8mbs in size.  I want input from a user, say **id, and I want to show all possible matches, where * can be any letter A-Z. (said, maid, etc)

I'm looking for some suggestions on the most efficient way to do this, because I want the user to be able to add more concrete letters and give a live update of the word matches.

My idea was to attempt to use RegexKitLite, but i have a feeling that would be incredibly slow.

Thanks for any input!

Edit:  Do you think its possible to use NSPredicates to achieve this?

Comment: Whether it is possible to use NSPredicates really depends on your implementation of the data structures. BKTree, DAWG, GADDAG, whatever you end up with.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! To be a little clearer on my problem (for others), its very closely related to a "hangman solver algorithm."  I've been doing some research on a BKTree, but I haven't really found any good examples on their implementation, because honestly, I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Well, in case of "hangman" you may want to check out **GADDAG** (linked in my answer), as it is a special purpose data structure for "Scrabble" solving (which is structurally identical to "Hangman" solving).

Answer (score 4):

The things you can do to optimize search performace highly depends on how you want to limit the use of those wildcards.

Precisely: what are the characteristics of your wildcards?

- **prefix-only** wildcards (m/.+foobar/)
- **suffix-only** wildcards (m/foobar.+/)
- **atomic** wildcards (`m/./`)
- **dynamic** wildcards (`m/.+/`)

---

### Prefix-only Wildcards

Use a **[Prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree)** or [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)

---

### Suffix-only Wildcards

Use a **[Suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)** or [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)

---

### Atomic Wildcards

One way to drastically reduce the number of matches you have to run would be:

**Build a [BKTree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees)** from your **word collection**.

As (and as long as) your wildcard has a fixed length (1 in your case) you could then simply query your BKTree for nodes with an exact edit distance of `n`, with `n` being the number of wildcards. Traditional **BKTree queries have an upper limit of variance**. In your case you'd want to **introduce an additional lower limit**, narrowing the range of accepted variance down to exactly `[n,1]` (vs. traditionally `[0,n]`).
You'll get an array of words differing from your query word by ecactly `n` characters.

For the query `**id` some possible matches would be:

- `void` (2x additions)
- `laid` (2x additions)
- `bad` (1x replacement, 1x addition)
- `to` (2x replacements)

While those are **not yet correct matches for your query**, the represent a **very small subset** of your total collection of words.

So last but not least you **run your Regex matching againt those results** and **return all remaining matches**.

**BKTrees** introduce the **levenshtein distance as some spatial heuristic** to drastically (**depending on the entropy** within your word collection) **reduce the number of required comparisons/matchings**.

To gain **additional optimization** you could use **multiple BKTrees**:

Divide your collection into sub-sets. One set for words of length `1`, one for length `2`, one for `3`, and so on. From each subset you then build a BKTree. For a query `**id` you'd then query the **BKTree** for length 4 (wildcards are counted like chars).
This applies for wildcards getting interpreted as `m/./`. If your wildcard however shall get interpreted as `m/.?/` you'd query the **BKTrees** for length 3 & 4.

---

**Alternatively** to **BKTrees** you could also use a [**GADDAG**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADDAG), which is a data structure (specialization of Trie) specialized particularly for Scrabble-style lookups.

If I'm not mistaken your wildcards will need to get interpreted strictly as `m/./` as well.

---

### Dynamic Wildcards

Cannot right now think of any significantly better solution than running your regex against your collection of words.

Comment: "Regex" by name as well as by nature, eh?

Comment: @josh-caswell: For sure ;) Thinking about it I actually did use Regex before I could program, back when I was 15 or so. O_o As such these days I find text editors without Regex search/replace support hardly usable. I use Regexes ALL THE TIME. Only sparingly in code though. ;) So yeah, if a question gets tagged *regex* you'll probably see me in there somehow, somewhen, eventually. ;)